# Docker, Python, and "import logging"

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have trying to build a docker image/container that is Python 3.8.2 and that will run a specific script when ran. I can get it to build but when I try and run it breaks.

Specifically, I am running into a problem where:

```
...
import grpc
...
```

gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project1/script1.py", line 4, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.pyx", line 27, in init grpc._cython.cygrpc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 42, in <module>
    LOGGER = logging.getLogger("concurrent.futures")
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'
```

HOWEVER,
if i use the

```
docker run -it <image name> sh
```

to run the image, if I try to run pip in the Docker containers command line I get the same error.

Here is the Dockerfile used to create the image:

```
FROM python:3.8.2

#Build the Python Environments
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install "obspy==1.2.1"

#COPY project1
COPY project1 /

#Update PYTHON PATH to include project1
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/project1"

#Run the script1.py script
CMD python /project1/script1.py
```

All of this runs fine on my windows box in a Python 3.8.2 environment that contains all the packages in requirements.txt

Anyone have any suggestions on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

May be try with a different python version image.

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning the specific version of the dependency  in requirements.txt file

Comment: doesn't seem to be dependency based since pip gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Is there any python file named `logging.py` or module folder named `logging` in your project? If so try give it another name.